# RSpec + Rubocop - why receive_message_chain is a code smell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I am about to write specs for my custom validator, that uses this chain to check if a file attach with ActiveStorage is a txt:

`return if blob.filename.extension.match?('txt')`

Normally, I would be able to stub it with this call:

`allow(attached_file).to receive_message_chain(:blob, :byte_size) { file_size }`

Rubocop says it is an offence and points me to docs: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/MessageChain

I would have to declare double for `blob` and `byte_size` and stub them in separate lines, ending up with 5 lines of code instead of 1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/smells/message-chains

Comment: "Chains can be arbitrarily long, which makes it quite painless to violate the Law of Demeter
in violent ways, so you should consider any use of receive_message_chain a code smell. [....] `receive_message_chain` results in brittle examples". Taken from https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains

Comment: Thanks, I've already read both of those sources, but there's really not much I can do about getting extension "faster" - I could create my own method and pass `blob` to it, that will undercover call `.filename.extension`, but do you think it's really worth it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why should I avoid stubbing message chains?**

> I would have to declare double for blob and byte_size and stub them in separate lines, ending up with 5 lines of code instead of 1.

This is, in fact, the point. Having those 5 lines there likely will make you feel slightly uneasy. This can be thought of as *positive design pressure*. Your test setup being complex is telling you to have a look at the implementation. Using `#receive_message_chains` allows us to feel good about designs that expose complex interactions up front.

One of the authors of RSpec explains some of this in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/921#issuecomment-91418492).

**What can I do instead?**

One option is to attach a fixture file to the record in the setup phase of your test:

```
before do
  file_path = Rails.root.join("spec", "fixtures", "files", "text.txt")

  record.attribute.attach(io: File.open(file_path), filename: "text.txt")
end
```

This will test the validator end-to-end, without any stubbing.

---

Another option is to extract a named method, and then stub that instead.

In your validator:

```
def allowed_file_extension?
  blob.filename.extension.match?("txt")
end
```

In your test:

```
before do
  allow(validator).to receive(:allowed_file_extension?).and_return(true)
end
```

This has the added benefit of making the code a little clearer by naming a concept. (There's nothing preventing you from adding this method even if you use a test fixture.)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a counterpoint, I frequently get this rubocop violation with tests around logging like:

```
expect(Rails).to receive_message_chain(:logger, :error).with('limit exceeded by 1')
crank_it_up(max_allowed + 1)
```

I could mock Rails to return a double for logger, then check that the double receives :error.  But that's a bit silly, IMO. `Rails.logger.error` is more of an idiom than a message chain.

I could create a `log_error` method in my model or a helper (and sometimes I do), but often that's just a pointless wrapper for `Rails.logger.error`

So, I either end up disabling RSpec/MessageChain for that line, or perhaps for the entire project (since I would *never* abuse it for real...right?) It would be nice if there was a way to be more selective about disabling/muting this cop across the project...but I'm not sure how that could work, in any case.

Comment: it's a valid point in some circumstances, but in this specific example, you can say:


`expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with('whatever you expect')`